Integral of exponential function multiplied by sine function

Question: Find $\displaystyle\int e^x\sin x\,dx$

Let $I = \displaystyle\int e^x\sin x\,dx$
Then
$$
I = e^x (-\cos x) - \int\bigl[e^x(-\cos x)\bigr]\,dx
$$
Integrating $e^x(-\cos x)$:
$$
I = -e^x\cos x - \biggl[e^x(-\sin x) - \int\bigl[e^x(-\sin x)\bigr]\,dx\biggr]
$$
Integrating $e^x(-\sin x)$:
$$
I = -e^x\cos x - e^x(-\sin x) + \biggl[e^x\cos x - \int\bigl[e^x\cos x\bigr]\,dx\biggr]
$$
Integrating $e^x\cos x$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &= -e^x\cos x + e^x\sin x + e^x\cos x - \biggl[e^x\sin x - \int \bigl[e^x\sin x\bigr]\,dx\biggr] \\
&= -e^x\cos x + e^x\sin x + e^x\cos x - e^x\sin x + \int\bigl[e^x\sin x\bigr]\,dx \\
&= -e^x\cos x + e^x\sin x + e^x\cos x - e^x\sin x + I \\[5pt]
\implies I &= I
\end{aligned}$$
Where have I gone wrong in this?

Do integration by parts twice. Then the integral term is $I$ again. Move it to the LHS.

Okay, but why does this method give an error, I don't think I did anything incorrect ?

You proved a true statement. $I=I$ because anything equals itself. You proved a truth, just not a useful truth.

There is no error yet. Continue and do integration by parts six times in total. Then the integral term is $I$ again. Move it to the LHS.

Nothing is "wrong" with what you wrote. $I$ is indeed equal ro $I$ just like $5=5$ or $x=x$. Although to find the antiderivative of this function you can work like so:
After integrating by parts twice we have $$I=e^x\sin(x)-\left[e^x\cos(x)+\int e^x\sin(x)dx \right]$$ Which gives birth to the following linear equation in terms of $I$. Solving it for $I$ will give the closed form of the integral. $$I=e^x\sin(x)-\left[e^x\cos(x)+I\right]\iff I=\frac{1}{2}e^x(\sin(x)-\cos(x))$$

An alternative solution:
$$(e^x\sin x)'=e^x\sin x+e^x\cos x$$
$$(e^x\cos   x)'=e^x\cos x-e^x\sin x $$ Subtracting and dividing by $2$ lead to $${1\over 2}(e^x\sin x-e^x\cos  x)'=e^x\sin x$$ Besides, by adding and dividing by $2$ we obtain the antiderivative of $e^x\cos x.$
In this way we avoid applying  integrations by parts.
